C# скриншот области экрана с поиском по шаблону (Emgu CV v4.9)
Делаю скриншот области экрана, далее ищу совпадение по шаблону.
на строке
Image source = Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension.ToImage(bitmap);
выходит ошибка. (Emgu CV v4.9)
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;


using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
    
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RECT rect;
        rect.left = 0;
        rect.top = 0;
        rect.right = 1200;
        rect.bottom = 800;
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        using (bitmap)
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
        }

        //ОШИБКА В этой строчке
        
        Image<Bgr, Byte> source = Emgu.CV.BitmapExtension.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>(bitmap);
        //  и такой вариант не работает
        // Image<Bgr, Byte> source = bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();


        Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>("scr-over/temple.bmp");
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageToShow = source.Copy();
        using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
        {
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
            if (maxValues[0] > 0.9)
            {
                Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], template.Size);
                imageToShow.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 1);
                pictureBox1.Image = imageToShow.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
        imageToShow.Save("scr-over/результат.bmp");
        
    }



пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
